# How get the offset of term in Lucene?

Tags: c#, lucene, offset

I want to get the offset of one term in the Lucene . How can i get it ?

I vectored my content as

```
Field.TermVector.WITH_POSITIONS_OFFSETS
```

Is there any method in Lucene that give me offset of the term in one Document ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
TermPositionVector vector = (TermPositionVector) reader.getTermFreqVector(docId, myfield);
```

See http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_0_3/api/core/org/apache/lucene/index/TermPositionVector.html to get the info you want.