# Lucene Entity Extraction

Tags: lucene, text-mining, information-extraction, lucene-highlighter

Given a finite dictionary of entity terms, I'm looking for a way to do Entity Extraction with intelligent tagging using Lucene. Currently I've been able to use Lucene for:
 - Searching for complex phrases with some fuzzyness
 - Highlighting results

However, I 'm not aware how to:
 -Get accurate offsets of the matched phrases
 -Do entity-specific annotaions per match(not just  tags for every single hit)

I have tried using the explain() method - but this only gives the terms in the query which got the hit - not the offsets of the hit within the original text.

Has anybody faced a similar problem and is willing to share a potential solution?

Thank you in advance for you help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the offset, see this question: [How get the offset of term in Lucene?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2930339/how-get-the-offset-of-term-in-lucene)

I don't quite understand your second question. It sounds to me like you want to get the data from a [stored field](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_2/api/core/org/apache/lucene/document/Field.html) though. To get the data from a stored field:

```
TopDocs results = searcher.Search(query, filter, num);
foreach (ScoreDoc result in results.scoreDocs)
{
    Document resultDoc = searcher.Doc(result.doc);
    string valOfField = resultDoc.Get("My Field");
}
```

Comment: The above is to get the offset for a single Term, however, I need the offset of the full Phrase that has matched my search.   In terms of the stored field, how would I get the data directly from it for each on of the dictionary phrases?

Comment: @Dima_F: I added code to show how to use stored fields. wrt phrase offsets: I don't think you can. You can take a look at what the [highlighter does](http://www.docjar.org/html/api/org/apache/lucene/search/vectorhighlight/SimpleFragListBuilder.java.html), but your best bet might be to modifier the highlighter code to return the offset.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help on this! I will let you know where I can get with the Highlighter modification.